# Vector length error in function

Tags: r

I'm really struggling to debug this function and would be grateful for your help. The problem is in this line:

```
thres <- resultsHt$iithreshold
```

The error is:

```
There were 40 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
1: In x < (thres * max(x)) :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
etc...
```

However, my vector thres is the correct length:

```
> length(resultsHt$iithreshold)
[1] 40
```

This is the function:

```
library(data.table)
dataDT <- height[,13:ncol(height)] #Create a data frame containing CAG and height columns
dataDT <- setDT(dataDT) #Convert to a data table

colsToBeUsed<-names(dataDT[,!'CAG']) #Assigns the columns to be analysed

myFun <- function(x, mod, cag, thres) { #Function that takes vectors as arguments.
  x[x < (thres * max(x))] <- 0 #First sets all heights < 0.2*threshold to 0.
  norm_x <- x / sum(x) #Then normalises heights by dividing by the sum of the heights. 
  sum_x <- norm_x * (cag - mod) #Then multiplies by the change in CAG from mode
  sum(sum_x) #Then sums the results
} 

transision_matrix <- merge(propsettings, modeHt, by.x = "control", by.y = "sample") #Transition matrix that determines control modes for each sample
transision_matrix$mode <- resultsHt$mode #Adapting function for control modes to use sample modes (opposite to the way I normally develop the code). This allows 'mod' to be a vector of sample modes rather than control modes
setDT(transision_matrix)

mf2 <- function(colname, dataDT, transision_matrix){ #Function that takes column name and data table as arguments.
  x <- dataDT[, colname, with = F][[1]]
  mod <- transision_matrix[sample == colname, mode] #Vector of CONTROL modes to use
  cag <- dataDT[, "CAG"][[1]]
  thres <- resultsHt$iithreshold
  myFun(x, mod, cag, thres)
}

iiHt <- sapply(colsToBeUsed, function(x) mf2(x, dataDT, transision_matrix)) #Apply the mf2 function over the column name vector

resultsHt$iiHt <- iiHt
```

I've not included all tables and variables, but please let me know if useful

Comment: What is the length of `x <- dataDT[, colname, with = F][[1]]`?

Comment: The warning means that `x` and `thres` are of different lengths, so R's recycling rule for vector operations might not be doing what you expect.

Comment: Thanks both. I'm not sure how to find length of x. Unfortunately I had help creating the function. Could I trouble you to help me find out? I know the length of thres is 40, which is correct. Length(dataDT) is 41 if that helps. The first column of dataDT is 'CAG'

Comment: access the function using `debug(fun_name)`, before it executes the line with the trouble, you can verify their lengths.

Comment: Thanks. The line you wanted is 1078 long.    

Browse[2]> length(dataDT[, colname, with = F][[1]])
[1] 1078

Comment: That is for the current dataset, though it is 660 with another

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `thres` value, you're passing a threshold of 40 length vector, if you're trying to establish

Comment: Thanks, it works with other datasets using this formula, but not the particular one I'm trying to use at the moment. The function does work, just not all the time

Comment: Sorry bro, i was writing before and send incompletely my comment, so it goes now. The problem seems to be with the `thres` value, you're passing a threshold of 40 length vector, if you're trying to establish one unique threshold you should pre-process this vector earlier. The error happens in this line `  x[x < (thres * max(x))] <- 0, because `thres*max(x)` still has length 40, and it should be of length `1` of a integer divisor of `1078`.

Comment: Maybe the others datasets have a length which were multiple of `40`.

Comment: Thanks, like the mode, thres varies for each sample. That's why I wanted to use a vector. It works with a dataset of 660

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've managed to solve it with this:

thres <- settings$iithreshold[match(colname, settings$SampleFileName)]